# How can I get all DontDestroyOnLoad GameObjects?

Tags: unity, c#, destructables

I need to Destroy all `DontDestroyOnLoad` GameObjects.  But in order to do this, I first need to find them all.  I would prefer to automate this, opposed to having to manually reference each one.

`DontDestroyOnLoad` GameObjects seem to all be in the shared scene, `"DontDestroyOnLoad"`.  So I tried collecting all root GameObjects from this Scene, but it says it is an invalid scene.

```
private void DestroyDontDestroyOnLoadGameObjects()
{
    var dontDestoyOnLoadScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("DontDestroyOnLoad");
    var dontDestroyOnLoadGameObjects = dontDestoyOnLoadScene.GetRootGameObjects();
    foreach (var dontdestroyGameObject in dontDestroyOnLoadGameObjects)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

[image]

How can I Destroy all of the GameObjects that have `DontDestroyOnLoad` called on them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a cheeky little hackish method that **works only in the Editor**. We can't find the DontDestroyOnLoad scene by name, but every DontDestroyOnLoad'ed GameObject holds a reference to it. So, if we have a reference to just one such object (or create such an object) then we can get to all of them:

```
public void DestroyAllDontDestroyOnLoadObjects() {

   var go = new GameObject("Sacrificial Lamb");
   DontDestroyOnLoad(go);

   foreach(var root in go.scene.GetRootGameObjects())
       Destroy(root);

}
```

You can avoid creating a sacrificial object every time you need to operate on this list of objects by referencing one such object you know you'll always have in existence (say, the manager object that this script itself resides on), or by performing the ritual sacrifice once early in the run and caching a reference to the scene to use from then on (in my tests, it remains valid even after all its objects have been destroyed and new objects are marked DDOL)

Note that [according to the docs this trick won't work in a a built game](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiSceneEditing.html):

> You do not have access to the DontDestroyOnLoad scene and it is not
>   available at runtime.

Trying to access this scene will throw an exception complaining that the scene is invalid.

---

If the ritual sacrifice turns your stomach (with fair cause, I'd say) or **if you need this at runtime in a built game**, a more conventional approach would be to introduce a DontDestroyOnLoadManager like this:

```
public static class DontDestroyOnLoadManager
{
    static List<GameObject> _ddolObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    public static void DontDestroyOnLoad(this GameObject go) {
       UnityEngine.Object.DontDestroyOnLoad(go);
       _ddolObjects.Add(go);
    }

    public static void DestroyAll() {
        foreach(var go in _ddolObjects)
            if(go != null)
                UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(go);

        _ddolObjects.Clear();
    }
}
```

Then you can replace any instance of `DontDestroyOnLoad(someObject)` elsewhere in your codebase with `someObject.DontDestroyOnLoad()` (here I'm using an extension method to keep it concise, but you can also call it through your manager class explicitly). This wraps the native DontDestroyOnLoad and also performs the necessary bookkeeping to find all those objects later. The downside is if you have additional 3rd-party scripts & plugins that call DontDestroyOnLoad, you'd need to modify them to be tracked by this system.

Comment: Clever! Thanks! Won't the first one work during runtime though?

Comment: Nope, not in the built game. I tested it and it throws exceptions, as noted in the answer. Would be cool if it did, but honestly with how hacky it is, I'm not surprised that it doesn't. ;)

Comment: ah, i didnt see the edit.  well thanks again for yet another one of your awesome answers!

Comment: I think its backward.  You can only cross-edit scenes during runtime.  From your URL:  `Cross-Scene references are not supported, and are prevented in Edit mode. In Play mode they are allowed, because Scenes cannot be saved.`
I believe the section you were referring to is for Unity v5.3 and earlier.
And it works in during runtime for me.  Considering you cannot have DontDestroyOnLoad GameObjects before pressing play, this occurring in the editor should be a non-issue.

Comment: This isn't about Play Mode vs Edit Mode, it's about running a built executable versus running in play mode inside the editor. It works in play mode in the editor, but not in a built executable.

Comment: ah, gotcha. my mistake. tested and confirmed you are correct. thanks!

Comment: One possible application is to put the hacky version inside the manager version​, inside an `#IF UNITY_EDITOR` directive. There it can compare the objects in the DontDestroyOnLoad scene against our bookkeeping list, firing warnings if you've missed using the wrapper somewhere and a stray DontDestroyOnLoad object has been created outside of our list.

Answer (score 0):

````
public class DeleteDontDestroyOnLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        // Get all root GameObjects in the scene
        GameObject[] rootObjects = UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene().GetRootGameObjects();

        // Loop through each root GameObject
        foreach (GameObject rootObject in rootObjects)
        {
            // Check if the GameObject is marked as DontDestroyOnLoad
            if (IsDontDestroyOnLoad(rootObject))
            {
                // Destroy the GameObject
                Destroy(rootObject);
            }
        }
    }

    bool IsDontDestroyOnLoad(GameObject obj)
    {
        // Check if the GameObject has DontDestroyOnLoad flag
        return obj.scene.name == null;
    }
}
```
````